# Rails 5, Nginx, Puma, Rails admin - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, rails-admin

I would like to know how to enforce SSL in a rails 5 app. The app works fine in development. In production some POST requests over SSL via rails admin do not work.

If SSL is enforced via production.rb, the browser returns:

```
"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
```

And if "force_ssl" is set to false, some "POST" requests via rails admin return:

```
HTTP Origin header (https://www.example.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://www.example.com)
```

Thanks in advance.

These are the app settings:

**production.rb**

```
  # ...
  config.force_ssl = true
  # ...
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/bgc/apps/domain/shared/tmp/sockets/domain-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot 
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;


  root /home/bgc/apps/domain/current/public;
  access_log /home/bgc/apps/domain/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/bgc/apps/domain/current/log/nginx.error.log info;


  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: why not redirecting port 80 to port 443 to separate the server config, afterwards there must be a loop somewhere, can you check the access logs of nginx and logs in rails?
`server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;
 server_name _;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is pretty simple. When you are using the Nginx server with ssl, it will already sort out the ssl for you. If you remove `config.force_ssl = true` from production.rb and it will be sorted.